# Best functional-style syntax to build this object?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

The below code achieves desired output.  Is there a more elegant way to do this?

For example, is there some native javascript function like `flatMap` etc that would help?

(I know I could get rid of the intermediate variable `pieces`).

```js
const config = {
    fieldName1: {
        validation: "schema1",
        value: "abcvalue here"
    },
    fieldName2: {
        validation: "schema2",
        value: "abcvalue here"
    },
}

// Desired output: 
// {
//     fieldName1: "schema1",
//     fieldName2: "schema2",
//     ...
// }
const extractValidation = (config) => {
    const pieces = Object.entries(config).map(
        ([key, val]) => ({
            [key]: val.validation
        })
    )
    return Object.assign({}, ...pieces)
}


extractValidation(config)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more concise, and I think prettier, to pair `fromEntries` with a map over `.entries`.

```js
const config = {
    fieldName1: {
        validation: "schema1",
        value: "abcvalue here"
    },
    fieldName2: {
        validation: "schema2",
        value: "abcvalue here"
    },
}

const extractValidation = (config) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(config).map(([k,v]) => [k, v.validation])
);

console.log(extractValidation(config))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how I would do it.
By leveraging Ramda, you can go point-free and use `map` to any Functor

```js
const fn = R.map(R.prop('validation'));

const data = {
  fieldName1: {
    validation: "schema1",
    value: "abcvalue here"
  },
  fieldName2: {
    validation: "schema2",
    value: "abcvalue here"
  },
};

console.log(
  fn(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-ZZcBsXW4OcbCTfDlXbzGCamH1cANkg6EfZAN2ukOl7s5q8skbB+WndmAqFT8fuMzeuHkceqd5UbIDn7fcqJFgg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `reduce` so you can skip the `Object.assign`:

```js
Object.entries(config).reduce((o, [k, v]) => (o[k] = v.validation, o), {})
//=> {fieldName1: 'schema1', fieldName2: 'schema2'}
```